# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x" for a custom module

Tags: python, import, module

I've writtern a script called "utilities.py" which contains some functions I'd like to call from another script. This second script is in the same directory of the module, and when I try to run:

```
import utilities
```

I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities'
```

I've read something on the internet but I'm not really understanding how to treat modules in python, It's the first time I'm trying to do this, some help?

Comment: `from . import utilities` works?

Comment: Hi! I get this error : `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

Comment: add an empty init.py in the same folder, after that?

Comment: It didn't work, but I think I solved the problem, My folder was not included in `sys.path`. After I appended the path to that list even the single `import utilities` worked

Comment: Well that's one way to solve it, how were you executing the file?